# Using 'delete' before reassigning value for pointer is redudant?

Tags: c++

Should I use 'delete' in the following example?

```
int main(){
T object;
T* pointer = new T[4];
delete[] pointer; // this line is redudant? or error?
pointer = &object;
}
```

I'm asking Chat GPT this same question and it says: "the line delete is redudant and may lead to undefined behaviour, because when you re-assign the pointer, the data on heap is automatically deallocated". But i have a doubt about this. So should I use 'delete' there?

Comment: `delete[] pointer` is required to avoid memleak.

Comment: Don't trust Chat-GPT with C++ (or any programming questions). The line is not redundant, you'll leak the memory without it.

Comment: I was writing an assignment operator for a class, where I have to delete the current object data on heap before giving it a new memory. But when i added the delete line it gives error .And then jumped to chat GPT and it responsed so :>

Comment: Well, you should ask a question about the error you got (including [mcve] - minimal code that produces this error and the error itself) instead of asking ChatGPT and then asking us about what ChatGPT hallucinated.

Comment: If you have problems with your class, please post a minimal reproducible example and the error messages you get. The code you posted does not have any errors.

Comment: Note Chat GPT is a language model. All it knows is how to string together probable tokens. It can't tell if the result is actually correct because it doesn't understand what it just wrote.

Comment: my cat knows more about c++ than chatgpt. I dont have a cat but nevertheless.

Comment: You should not do the example at all. We hardly use any `new` or `delete` in modern C++, so just don't. But *if* you use `new` and `delete` (you shouldn't, but just assume for the sake of argument that you do), then that `delete` line is neither redundant nor an error. Also please read the [generative AI policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/4581301)

Comment: You should use std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr instead of new/delete. (When you need dynamic polymorphism). Otherwise manage memory using containers like std::vector

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just a mess thats all about chatGPT at this point.

Comment: @OP read the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and check anything related to new/delete and raw pointers. Those guidelines is what ChatGPT should have learned.

Comment: This question needs to remain available. I want to be able to point to it as a demonstration of how these chat AIs are not actually smart.

Comment: *I'm asking Chat GPT this same question and it says:* -- When you are learning something new, you want to go to peer-reviewed books, articles, and if available, examples, advice, etc. from people from the industry.  You shouldn't go ask some AI engine for the answers.  This is especially the case for written code, where there is an infinite combination of ways you could have written your code, and the AI engine has to be familiar with all of those combinations to give any kind of valid answer.

Comment: @sweenish the accidental canonical, eh? I support this. Even though it's merely a single datapoint, it does show just how wrong-headed a language model can be with respect to a language it's not designed to model.

Comment: @sweenish I tweeted it, just in case :P

Comment: Shouldn't that be you Xed it?

Comment: @user4581301 there is an answer on my ques. wouldn't be a good deed if I'd do such thing.

Comment: If you are referring to my suggestion that you heavily modify the question, I removed that comment shortly after the answer appeared. If you're referring to something else... I need a bit more meat to know what you're talking about.

Comment: That said, it's probably been long enough for the question cooldown to expire. Feel free to ask a new question targeting the over-problem.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry I was mistaken

Comment: Goes to show that ChatGPT is only as good as the data it is trained with.   Garbage in results in garbage out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "the line delete is redudant and may lead to undefined behaviour, because when you re-assign the pointer, the data on heap is automatically deallocated"

This is utter nonsense.

What you create via `new` you must eventually be deleted via `delete` (and `delete []` for what has been allocated via `new []`). The line does not lead to undefined behavior. It is also not redundant, because if you do not delete the array you have a memory leak. Reassinging the pointer does not deallocate the memory it was pointing to.

It should be noted that you should not use `new` in the first place. Raw owning pointers are dangerous and will lead to problems. Use `std::vector`, other containers, and smart pointers for dynamic memory managment, but don't do it manually.

Comment: Time for the OP to research smart pointers.